# SQL Service Broker creating objects in SQL Server Database Project in VS 2012

Tags: t-sql, database-project, service-broker

So I've started a SQL Server database project inside VS 2012. I have done this for other databases already but not related to Service Broker.

For testing I had already created db, queues, etc through a T-SQL script including Message Types which was in an XML format.  i.e.

[//blah.com/Items/RequestItem]

When I try to do something like this in the DB Project it's not allowing me too due to special chars.

Anyone done this? Gotten around it?

Is there a way to simply put my already created T-SQL file in the database project and have it use it?

Comment: Well I think I may have just found it.  Right clicked on Database Project and Ran Import wizard.  Not excited about the structure it inferred.  But it seems to have imported all my objects correctly.

Comment: You can move those scripts/objects around pretty freely once they're in the project. It may also help if you use the "Schema View" option in the later releases of SSDT to view the structure instead of the default Project View. :)

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above.  I was able to import the script by Right clicking on the database Project.